# When to use ViewFlipper?

Tags: android

I have an input wizard type activity with 2 views and a ViewFlipper. Each view takes up the entire screen and sets it's own title. I combined them because it was a packaged deal, you will never access view2 without first going through view1 and 99% of the time if you access view1, you will access view2.

Is this a recommended setup? Is there any cons to using it this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's just perfect. In fact, if you are 99% sure that you will have 2 views only, it's recommended to use `ViewSwitcher`. But using `ViewFlipper` is OK.